# Chart.js coloring the shape in a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, point, fill

I have a chart I created with Chart.js. In this chart, I have four points and these points are connected and a quadrilateral is obtained and the inside is colored green. But in this way, the y-axis points are painted higher even though they are lower, and the right place remains unpainted even though the points are lower. How can this unpainted area be painted?

[image: When you add 4 points]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('workingLimitGraph').getContext('2d');
        var minFluidOutletTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MinFluidOutletTemp;
        var maxFluidOutletTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MaxFluidOutletTemp;
        var minAmbientTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MinAmbientTemp;
        var maxAmbientTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MaxAmbientTemp;

        var xAxisMin = minFluidOutletTemp - 5;
        var xAxisMax = maxFluidOutletTemp + 5;
        var yAxisMin = minAmbientTemp - 10;
        var yAxisMax = maxAmbientTemp + 10;

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: [
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp }
                    ],
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    showLine: true
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Water Outlet Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 1,
                            padding: 20,
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        min: xAxisMin,
                        max: xAxisMax,
                        stepSize: 1,
                    },
                    y: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Ambient Air Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 10,
                            padding: 20,
                        },
                        min: yAxisMin,
                        max: yAxisMax,
                        stepSize: 10,
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // X ekseninin etiketlerini oluşturma
        var xAxisLabels = [];
        for (var i = minFluidOutletTemp - 3; i <= maxFluidOutletTemp + 3; i += 1) {
            xAxisLabels.push(i);
        }

        myChart.data.labels = xAxisLabels;
        // Y ekseninin etiketlerini oluşturma
        var yAxisLabels = [];
        for (var i = yAxisMin; i <= yAxisMax; i += 10) {
            yAxisLabels.push(i);
        }
        myChart.options.scales.y.ticks.callback = function (value, index, values) {
            return value;
        };
        //koordinat değerlerini hesaplama
        $('#workingLimitGraph').mousemove(function (event) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('workingLimitGraph');
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

            var chartInstance = myChart;
            var chartArea = chartInstance.chartArea;

            var xValue = (x - chartArea.left) / (chartArea.right - chartArea.left) * (xAxisMax - xAxisMin) + xAxisMin;
            var yValue = (chartArea.bottom - y) / (chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top) * (yAxisMax - yAxisMin) + yAxisMin;

            if (xValue < xAxisMin + 5) {
                xValue = xAxisMin + 5;
            } else if (xValue > xAxisMax - 5) {
                xValue = xAxisMax - 5;
            }

            if (yValue < yAxisMin + 10) {
                yValue = yAxisMin + 10;
            } else if (yValue > yAxisMax - 10) {
                yValue = yAxisMax - 10;
            }

            $('#xCoordinate').text(xValue.toFixed(2));
            $('#yCoordinate').text(yValue.toFixed(2));
        });
```

```css
.symbol {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: default;
}

.tooltip-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: red;
    border-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: left 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.symbol:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="WLGModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="WLGModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title custom-font-size" id="WLGModalLabel">Working Limit Graph</h6>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close mr-2 mt-1" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="coordinatesLabel" class="text-center">
                    <div class="custom-font-size">
                        Water Outlet Temperature:
                        <span id="xCoordinate"></span>
                        Ambient Air Temperature:
                        <span id="yCoordinate"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <canvas id="workingLimitGraph" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
                    <div id="draggableSymbol" class="symbol">×</div>
                    <div id="tooltipBox" class="tooltip-box" style="display: none;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; width: 100%;">
                    <div>
                        <span id="WaterOutletModal" class="custom-font-size">Water Outlet Temperature (°C): </span><br>
                        <span id="AmbientTempModal" class="custom-font-size">Ambient Ait Temperature (°C): </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mb-2">
                            <i class="fas fa-check mr-3" style="color: #09be88;"></i>OK
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you make five points, it frames the shape correctly, but this time it does not paint inside. The inside of this shape must be painted.

```js
data: [
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp }
                    ],
```

[image]